# React on GitHub Pages refresh url notfound

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, react-router-dom

Lately I hosted my react app on Github Pages and it seems to work, but when I refresh the page I get 404 Not Found. I understand why it happens, because my GitHub can't find any application on this URL, despite that it's valid for my application. I've read that I can fix it with HashRouter, but the problem is that the react router official docs are down for some days now. If you have any experience with HashRouter or you have different solution, please share it!

Return in my App.js

```
return (
  <div>
    <Navigation redirect={this.redirect} />
    <HashRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/Login' render={(props) => requireAnonymous(Login, props)} />
        <Route path='/Register' render={(props) => requireAnonymous(Register, props)} />
        <Route path='/Calendar' render={(props) => requireAuthentication(Calendar, props)} />
        <Route path='/Todo/:date' render={(props) => requireAuthentication(TodoContainer, props)} />
      </Switch>
    </HashRouter>
  </div>
);
```

You are welcome to suggest another improvements in my code!

Comment: [Check this](https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages) for using local routing with BrowserRouter in SPAs

Comment: [hachRouter Docs][1]


  [1]: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter

Comment: The link gives me Error 522 Connection timed out. And it does that for a whole week.